# Create a command in Symfony5 that executes several times from an hour

Tags: symfony

I would like to know how to create a command in Symfony 5 that executes several times from an hour.
I give you an example:

1. Create a command that we will call with the option

```sh
app:schedule-command
```

[https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cloud/cookbooks/crons.html)

2. The content of the command will be only this:

```php
echo "Hello world";
```

3. This command will be executed every 5 minutes, every day from 11:00pm to 11:30pm.

NOTE: This is not valid for me:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/cloud/cookbooks/crons.html

(use Symfony Cloud, and i want to test in local)

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this cron:
`0-30/5 23 * * * bin/console app:schedule-command`

For testing locally, if you are under linux or macOS, CRON are working as well. If you are under windows, you can use the Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, PierrickM!

The cron is correct.
For example, on Linux I do this:

```
crontab -e
0-30/5 23 * * * date >> ~/date.txt
```

The Cron executes command date and the output is write into user directory every day from 23:00 to 23:30 each 5 minutes.

But I want another thing:
The steps will be...

1. Create a command that just executes this:

```
    echo "Hello world"
```

This command will be called with **app: schedule-command**.

2. Create another command (a "meta command") called app: **schedule-execute** that calls the previous one as a cron task.
   For example, like this:

```
* * * * * bin / console app: schedule-command.
```

Thanks again everyone.